# Как удалить значения из трёх связанных таблиц одновременно?

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

Суть проблемы: есть 3 таблицы в MySQL, связанные между собой ключами. По непонятной причине в заглавной таблице (`indicator`) появились дублирующие записи, которые не нужны, но удалить их не получается, потому что к ним привязаны записи в `monitoring_result`, а к тем - записи из `monitoring_results_methods`.

Возможно ли каким-то образом удалить все записи `monitoring_results_methods`, связанные с `monitoring_result` (и сами записи в `monitoring_result`), которые связанны с записью в `indicator` в одном запросе?

Сделать это руками физически невозможно - записей огромное количество.

Содержание таблиц:

`indicator`:

- id
- parent_id
- title
- code
- report_form_id
- index_number
- type

`monitoring_result`:

- id
- indicator_id (indicator.id)
- method_id
- report_id
- report_template_id
- total_value
- custom_method
- is_visible

`monitoring_result_method`:

- result_id (monitoring_result.id)
- method_id

Comment: Посмотрите [Multi-Table Deletes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/delete.html). Также можете посмотреть [тут](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-delete-join/)

Comment: Поставьте на ключах связывающих таблицы ON DELETE CASCADE и при удалении записи из родительской таблицы автоматически будут удаляться все записи в дочерних

Comment: Собственно каскадное удаление прописано в сущностях symfony. Это не решает проблемы.

Comment: @Alexandr спасибо за ссылки, получилось удалить значения в monitoring_result_method указав id indicator, но как удалить еще и записи в monitoring_result ?

Вот то что есть на данный момент:
DELETE monitoring_results_methods FROM monitoring_results_methods INNER JOIN monitoring_result ON monitoring_result.id = monitoring_results_methods.result_id WHERE monitoring_result.indicator_id = 6424

Comment: @navasiolau `DELETE indicator, monitoring_result, monitoring_result_method FROM indicator LEFT JOIN monitoring_result ON monitoring_result.indicator_id = indicator.id LEFT JOIN monitoring_result_method ON monitoring_result_method.result_id = monitoring_result.id WHERE indicator.id = 6424`

Comment: Получаю вот такую ошибку:
#1451 - Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`dev`.`monitoring_results_methods`, CONSTRAINT `FK_462798667A7B643` FOREIGN KEY (`result_id`) REFERENCES `monitoring_result` (`id`))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
START TRANSACTION;

DELETE FROM monitoring_results_methods m
WHERE result_id in (
   SELECT id FROM monitoring_result
   WHERE indicator_id = 5000
);  

DELETE FROM monitoring_result
WHERE indicator_id = 5000;

DELETE 
FROM indicator 
WHERE indicator.id = 5000;

COMMIT;
```

Проблема решена с помощью транзакции с тремя запросами.